# VMware Library Not Saving

Tags: vmware, libraries

I installed vmware player yesterday into Ubuntu 12.04. It is VMware Player 5.0.0. on top of Ubuntu 12.04. My problem is the fact the library refuses to save upon reboot. I start a fresh library upon every reboot. Is there a way to keep the library upon reboot?